# Development console details lost in Rails 5 upgrade?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I upgraded my Rails 4 app to Rails 5, and now my development console is extremely non-verbose. I'm wondering if I did something wrong or if anyone has any other insight as to why I could be experiencing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was:

In development.rb

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

needed to be changed to:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the console that is displayed in command line?

I found it with Puma that the console performs completely different depending on how you start it. For instance startng it with

```
Puma
```

will show only starting block like so

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

And a good old

```
rails s
```

will display all the interactions that happen on the server.

Comment: I'm starting my server like this: rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me

Comment: And yes - in terminal, I'm expecting details to be outputted like they were in Rails 4.